# How to create subfolder and document on Firestore web?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm newbie with Firebase and I want use Firestore to store the user register content. I've a collection called 'users', and each user have a 'register' that must contains a JSON Document and a 'monthlies' that must be a collection or a array of documents. At the moment I tried just add the 'register' document with two fields:

```
async saveUser(user) {
      var db = firebase.firestore();
      await db
        .collection("users")
        .doc(user.uid)
        .doc("register")
        .set(
          {
            name: user.displayName,
            email: user.email
          },
          {
            merge: true
          }
        );
    },
```

but the error is shows:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: db.collection(...).doc(...).doc is not a function
    at _callee$ (Login.vue?7463:75)
    at tryCatch (runtime.js?96cf:45)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (runtime.js?96cf:271)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (runtime.js?96cf:97)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:3)
    at _next (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:25)
    at eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:32)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at VueComponent.eval (asyncToGenerator.js?1da1:21)
    at VueComponent.saveUser (Login.vue?7463:75)
```

So, How I can create this structure and update easyest?

Answer (score 3):

With Firestore, documents can't contain immediately nested documents.  If you want to organize a document under another document, you will need to choose a name of a subcollection, then use that to build documents nested in that subcollection:

```
await db
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection("data")
    .doc("register")
    .set(...)
```

Here, I just chose the name "data" for a subcollection.  You should organize your data in a way that makes sense for the queries you intend to perform.

Answer (score 1):

As Doug answered, you can store those values in a nested collection.

But if the values are singular (they're not a collection), I'd typically store them directly in the user document. So:

```
async saveUser(user) {
  var db = firebase.firestore();
  await db
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .set(
      {
        name: user.displayName,
        email: user.email
      },
      {
        merge: true
      }
    );
},
```

If you are already storing other data for the user, you can store the new data as nested fields in that same document with:

```
async saveUser(user) {

  var db = firebase.firestore();
  await db
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user.uid)
    .set({
      register: {
        "name": user.displayName,
        "email": user.email
      }}, {
        merge: true
      }
    );
},
```

Comment: in the nested example, you added quotes around `name` -- any reason why to do so?

Comment: Ah, I earlier had done "register.name" to reach the nested field, which requires the quotes. But the I realize the nested `register` object might make more sense.